# Passing an enviornment variable to executed process in Maven

Tags: java, maven-2, netbeans, exec-maven-plugin

I've been banging my head against a wall for about an hour on this: I'm trying to pass a simple property (`java.library.path`) to exec-maven-plugin. The goal is to have it integrate with Netbeans Right Click file > Run File procedure.

So I set my POM like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <java.library.path>native/win32-x86</java.library.path>
                </environmentVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

(I use an old version so I can see the execution args, but its fully reproducible with 1.2)

Then I right click my file and click "Run File". Netbeans starts this process:

```
 W:\programming\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin\mvn.bat -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime -Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath org.quackedcube.camera.CameraDemo -Dexec.executable=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\java.exe -Dnetbeans.execution=true -Dmaven.repo.local=W:\programming\maven-repo process-classes exec:exec
```

(The original full classpath execution was changed to `exec:exec` so hopefully my configuration applied)

But my environment variable is apparently ignored, as the resulting executed program is:

```
 Result of cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\java.exe" -classpath *snip* org.quackedcube.camera.CameraDemo" execution is: '1'.
```

I've tried

- Using separate Key and Value tags inside an enviornmentVariable tag
- Use a key and value tag directly inside an enviornmentVariables tag (worth a try)
- binding to a phase
- passing as a maven arg and using exec:java instead
- Passing -Djava.library.path=native/win32-x86 as a Run argument and VM option in Project Configuration page

and all have failed. I'm really at a loss here.

I guess this is the disadvantage of using JNI in maven: You have to pass as an argument to your tests, your runtime, your module run POM, and your parent POM.

So my question: How can I pass a `java.library.path` property to an executed file? It would be nice if it integrated with Netbeans Run File functionality (therefor I don't have to change the class name in a POM, build, then run)

Comment: You need to clarify what you actually want to do. your command line is missing some quotes around params with spaces. I just wrote a simple cmd script to print environment variables and it does show me the java.library.path env variable declared in pom.xml. I believe if you want your libs to be available to java program on windows, they need to be in PATH or declared in -Djava.library.path Also you may want to specify a full path and not a relative one (e.g. ${projectbase}/native/win32-x86)

Comment: @Eugene Sorry about that. I want -Djava.library.path present on the executed process exec-maven-plugin. And I'll specify the full path when I figure out how to do this

Comment: I believe this is a known issue https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=262245

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Didn't know this, but apparently when doing this you need to put this property first. I didn't think it was necessary since the classpath isn't immediately executed, but apparently it does make a difference.

To fix it, I simply changed this in Project Properties > Actions > Run File via Main

```
exec.classpathScope=${classPathScope}
exec.args=-Djava.library.path="native/win32-x86" -classpath %classpath ${packageClassName}
exec.executable=java
```

The reason you can't specifcy it in the POM is that NB passes the classpath and what its execution via command line `exec.args`, which overrides whats in your POM.

While this might be ugly and platform dependant, its what happens when you mix JNI and Maven. There isn't really another way that I can see.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you tried this but as long as you need to set property on a level of JVM it should be done with `-Djava.library.path=/some/path`

So in order to specify it for exec-maven-plugin you could write something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-Djava.library.path=${java.library.path}</argument>
    </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You need, of course, to update the executable and maybe add another attributes.

Comment: I did add `-Djava.library.path=${java.library.path}` to `exec.args` in the Netbeans actions, but it seemed to be interpreted as part of the whole argument list for maven. When escaping the quotes, I got a "invalid parameter error" (or something like that). And even if I specifically set it in my pom, Netbeans will override it in the command line

Comment: As far as I understand you're calling Maven from NetBeans and from Maven you need to call another eternal process. Thus you use exec-maven plugin. The trick is that arguments specified for Maven execution in the Netbeans aren't passed to exec-maven plugin directly. Instead you need to specify them in POM itself. Did you try to specify parameters in POM file as I wrote above?

Comment: I did try and couldn't get it to work. I did find out the simpler but platform/IDE dependent way in my answer. If you have any other suggestions please tell me.:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951818/passing-an-enviornment-variable-to-executed-process-in-maven/3979239#3979239